# Finding unique groups of C11 semidirect product C5

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, group-isomorphism

Find unique groups of form $$ C_{11}\rtimes C_5$$ (semi-direct product) with homomorphism 
$$h:C_5\rightarrow Aut(C_{11})$$

I've found the possible homomorphisms i.e $$h=Id,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^9 $$
So performing (1,y)*(x,1) calculation we'll get $$C_{11}XC_5$$ and groups with relations $$YX=X^3Y,YX=X^4Y,YX=X^5Y,YX=X^9Y$$ Are these five groups distinct? Have I done this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to isomorphism, there are only two such groups. One is the abelian one. So you have to show that the remaining four are isomorphic.

---

To see this, consider the group defined by the first relation:
$$
\langle X, Y : X^{11} = Y^5 = 1, Y X Y^{-1} = X^{3} \rangle.
$$
Take $Z = Y^{2}$. Then
$$
Z X Z^{-1} = Y^{2} X Y^{-2} = Y X^{3} Y^{-1} = (Y X Y^{-1})^{3}= X^{9}. 
$$
So the group above is the same as
$$
\langle X, Z : X^{11} = Z^5 = 1, Z X Z^{-1} = X^{9} \rangle,
$$
that is, the group defined by the fourth relation.

Do the same with $Z = X^{3}$ (you will find the group defined by the third relation) and $Z = X^{4}$ (you will find the group defined by the second relation).

Comment: I don't see how they could be isomorphic, surely the relations make them distinct?

Comment: @TheProblem, please see my edit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that really clears things up